# golang - prevent two posts of a static site generator from appearing on the post list (about is one)

Tags: go, themes, static-site-generation

Using an older ssg I found a way to prevent something from showing up but I have the wrong syntax. Here is the area of concern. This is list.html template and shows all posts.

```
{{ define "body" }}
{{ if .IsFiltered }}
    </br><h2>Topics: {{ .FilteredTag.Name }}</h2>&nbsp;&nbsp;
{{ else }}
   </br><h2>All posts</h2>
{{ end }}
<div class ="list">
    {{ range .Posts }}
        <a href="{{ .ID }}.html">{{ .Title }} </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ .Time.Format "2006-1-2" }}<br/>
    {{ end }}
</div>
{{ end }}
```

I need to add something similar to the following to prevent the "about" post from showing -

```
{{ if ne {{ .Title }} "about" }}
```

If I add it like this, I get an error -

```
{{ define "body" }}
{{ if .IsFiltered }}
    </br><h2>Topics: {{ .FilteredTag.Name }}</h2>&nbsp;&nbsp;
{{ else }}
   </br><h2>All posts</h2>
{{ end }}
<div class ="list">
    {{ range .Posts }}{{ if ne {{ .Title  }} "about" }}
        <a href="{{ .ID }}.html">{{ .Title }} </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ .Time.Format "2006-1-2" }}<br/>
    {{ end }}
</div>
{{ end }}
```

Can you see what's wrong? My error states "unexpected {"

Comment: I think you need to write it as `{{ if ne  .Title  "about" }}`

Comment: Just tried it and got this error - "unexpected EOF" for line 12.

Comment: I added the full code for list.html so you can see line 12, the last line.

Comment: You need to add {{ end }} for your if block

Comment: It works good. How do I give you credit?

Comment: I convert my comment into an answer, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write down your condition as follows:

```
{{ if ne  .Title  "about" }}
{{ end }}
```